# Can't replace whitespaces in value textarea when submiting form

Tags: php, textarea

I want to replace all whitespaces with one whitespace; I'm using this code:

```
$valuetextarea=trim(strval(preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $_POST['nametextarea'])));
```

But this code replace only line break.

Comment: Try the `g` modifier for global

Answer (score 0):

You can use `preg_replace`:

```
$valuetextarea = trim(preg_replace("/\ +/", " ", $_POST['nametexarea']));
```

Comment: The OP *is* using `preg_replace`